# selenium firefox Profile has been set on both the capabilities and these options but they're different. Unable to determine which one you want to use

Tags: selenium

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
```

$profile = new FirefoxProfile();
$profile->setPreference('log', "{level: info}");

$caps = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$caps->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $caps, 500000, 500000);

PHP version: 5.5
Selenium server version: 3.3
Operating system: win7
Browser used + version: firefox 52
geckodriver version:0.15

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in Selenium Server 3.3.1.

See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3632 .